# Error running RMI application in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, rmi

I am currently developing a simple RMI application in VSC using WSL. However, when I am running the application with VSC built-in run and debug feature with custom `launch.json`, it failed to execute and give me an error.

`Server.java`

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Interface{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:./security.policy");
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
            Server server = new Server();
            Naming.rebind("Server", server);
            System.out.println("Service registered");
        } catch (Exception error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public Server() throws RemoteException {
        super(0);
        System.out.println("Server is started");
    }

    public boolean login(String username, String password) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("Received login request");
        return true;
    }

    public boolean register(String username, String password) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("Received register request");
        return true;
    }
}
```

`Interface.java`

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Interface extends Remote {
    boolean login(String username, String password) throws RemoteException;

    boolean register(String username, String password) throws RemoteException;
}
```

`launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Launch Server",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "com.project.Server",
            "projectName": "project",
            "args": "-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=false"
        }
    ]
}
```

`Folder structure`

```
root
|_src
  |_main
    |_java
      |_com
        |_project
          |_Client.java
          |_Interface.java
          |_Server.java

|_other files..omitted for simplicity
```

I have also added the folder to Java source path inside VSC

Steps of my execution

```
1. run rmiregistry &
2. click Launch Server in VSC debug and run
```

The error I am having is

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.project.Interface
```

Is VSC limited in capability to run RMI application?

Comment: Can you share the folder structure?

Comment: I have just updated the question with folder structure.

Comment: I've also searched the web and found no related articles about running RMI application in VSC too.

Comment: It has nothing to do with VSC. Just your deployment.

Comment: May I know what path I should pass into `classpath`? The root folder or the project folder containing the code?

Comment: The head of the package structure of the compiled classes.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still cannot get it working. When I'm running RMI application in Eclipse, it can run without me compiling the source. Does that mean in VSC I have to manually use `rmic` to compile the source first and point the `classpath` to the compiled source? Again, thank you very much as this question already bothered me 2 days.

Comment: I can't advise you about VSC but the fundamental error is as per my answer in the duplicate.

Comment: You don't need to use rmic unless using a very old Java version, but classpath containing the interface `com.project.Interface` must be provided to rmiregistry. This can be set with CLASSPATH environment var or in command line: `rmiregistry -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///C:/yourpath/the-client.jar`.